# const castError = new CastError() CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value

Tags: reactjs, mongoose, postman, mern

[Error that shows after i send a post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQoMU.png)

**I'm creating  a facebook clone and currently working on the route to accept friend request which is a (Post method) .
when i test via postman i get the error CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value**

**accept friend request route**

```
router.post("/user/acceptMatchrequest", verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
    const recipientId = req.user
    const senderId = req.body.sender
    const updatedSender = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: senderId, matches: { $nin: [recipientId] } },
        { $push: { matches: recipientId } },
        { new: true }
    )
    const updatedRecipient = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: recipientId, matches: { $nin: [senderId] } },
        {
            $push: { matches: senderId },
        },
        { new: true }
    );
    if (updatedRecipient) {
        const updatedMatchRequest = await MacthRequest.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
                sender: senderId,
                recipient: recipientId,
            },
            {
                $set: { status: 'accepted' },
                $push: { friendshipParticipants: [senderId, recipientId] },
            },
            { new: true }
        );

        const updatedRequests = await MacthRequest.find({
            recipient: req.user,
            status: 'pending',
        });
        res.status(200).send({
            updatedRequests: updatedRequests,
            updatedUserFriendList: updatedRecipient.matches,
        });
    }

})
```

**my friend request schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const matchRequestSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        sender: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        recipient: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        status: {
            type: String,
        },
        friendshipParticipants: {
            type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
        }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model("matchRequest", matchRequestSchema);
```

**Users schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    matches: {
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        ref: 'User'
    },
 {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)
```

*The result after sending the post request*

- const castError = new CastError();
  CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{
  user: '62c1f76928dca4af2ec95010',
  isAdmin: true,
  iat: 1667490411,
  exp: 1667494011
  }" (type Object) at path "matches" for model "User"
  at model.Query.exec*

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that: `const recipientId = req.user` - the `req.user` is not the user id, but a user session object. So it is taking that session object (which looks like: `{ user: '62c1f76928dca4af2ec95010', isAdmin: true, iat: 1667490411, exp: 1667494011 }`) and trying to cast it to an `ObjectId` and failing.

I would try:

`const recipientId = req.user.user` which is setting the id to the id of the user making the request, instead of to the object.